# why this function return None to value?

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
total=0

def f(x):
    import math
    return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radio(start,stop,step):
    time=stop-start
    newstart=start+step

if time !=0:
    rad=f(start)*step
    global total
    total+=rad
    radio(newstart,stop,step)
else:
    return total
print radio(0, 5, 1)
print radio(5, 11, 1)
print radio(0, 11, 1)
print radio(40, 100, 1.5)
```

Comment: Because you are calling `radio` function which is returning nothing explicitly, so default it is returning `None` implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

In Python functions return `None` by default.

You have problem with indentation, therefore your function `radio` unexpectedly ends and the subsequent code block considered an independent and not belonging to the `radio`. To solve it - fix the indentation like this:

```
def radio(start,stop,step):
    time=stop-start
    newstart=start+step

    if time !=0:
        rad=f(start)*step
        global total
        total+=rad
        radio(newstart,stop,step)
    else:
        return total
```

Answer (score 0):

In python function has to give any return value if no return value are specified then by default `None` is returned

The first time you called radio function nothing was returned it called itself again due to which None was returned

TO avoid this problem since you are using recursive call you have return value of each function to other function so use return when calling the same function

```
total=0


def f(x):
    import math
    return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radio(start,stop,step):
    time=stop-start
    newstart=start+step

    if time !=0:
        rad=f(start)*step
        global total
        total+=rad
        return radio(newstart,stop,step)
    else:
        return total
print radio(0, 5, 1)
```

**Output:**

```
39.1031878433
```